# Manually Enter date in a (mm/dd/yy) format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

- If I start to enter any date in a field, it should be start as mm/dd/yy format. How can I do this using javascript or jquery.
- If I enter month as "01" then automatically should add one slash( " / " ), then If I add date as "30" the add one more slash( " / " ). Then year as also two digit.
- I do not allow to enter any other numbers. I want to enter only 8 characters including slash. (Ex : 01/06/16).

Please look at the fiddle.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du0a6tyu/8/)

I want to do this using javascript or jquery. But I dont want to use any plugin for this. Please help me how can I do this?

```js
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var checkin = jQuery('#startDate').fdatepicker({
  format: "mm/dd/yy",
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).data('datepicker');

jQuery("#startDate").fdatepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  format: "mm/dd/yy",
  language: 'en',
  todayHighlight: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://davis-design.de/marktadresse/layout/js/foundation-datapicker.js"></script>
<link href="http://davis-design.de/marktadresse/layout/css/foundation-datapicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="start_datum" class="input_text date" value="">
```

Comment: "*I dont want to use any plugin for this*", but foundation-datapicker.js is a plugin.

Comment: Yes I am using foudation datepicker plugin. I told for "mm/dd/yy" in this format I dont want to use any other plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code (add RRR modification, thanks RRR):

```
$("#startDate").keypress(
      function(){
        if($("#startDate").val().length>7)
            return false;
        if($("#startDate").val().length==2 || $("#startDate").val().length==5)
          {  
          $("#startDate").val($("#startDate").val() + "/");
          }});
```

Comment: month and day is ok. But year also it should allow only 2 digit. But it is allowing more than 2 digits. My format is "mm/dd/yy" only.

Comment: @RRR, It's also accepting the 60/56/09. any other solution?

Comment: You need jquey.validate

Answer (score 0):

There exist plugin for your request. You can try this plugin

[MASKED INPUT PLUGIN](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: I don't want to use any pluging regarding this validation.